# The Swiffy webservice could not be reached?

Tags: html, flash, connection, export, google-swiffy

I am trying to use swiffy for the first time, but upon trying to export as HTML5, it returns the following error:

**"The Swiffy webservice could not be reached. Please check your internet connection."**

I am definitely connected to the internet (Hence being able to ask this question).

So what could be wrong?

I anticipated a few difficulties, but this is just weird.

Many thanks!

Comment: Come on, I can't be the only person who has this problem! Googling the error message returns nothing. Can someone try installing the swiffy extension and see what it says for them? Anyone willing to convert a file for me? I'll give you £10 via paypal if you can figure out why its not working for me. I cant use the online converter, as there is a stupidly low 1mb maximum, which is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it!

I had to open up internet explorer (even if you don't use it normally, its just that swiffy uses this to connect to its web service) and go to:

tools > internet options > connections > LAN settings

and then turn on proxy.

Then it worked!

Funnily enough, I then turned this off and it still works?

Just glad to have it working!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your answer and it did not work. That, and the fact that your answer "works" even when not turned on, indicate that it was a coincidence, not the answer.

I've had this Swiffy problem twice (including now) in 12 months, figure it's just a blip in the network somewhere.

Comment: further to... switched off modem, waited 30 secs, switched on modem. Swiffy webservice now working.